# Use the space left from elements after transforming

Tags: css

Consider we have 10 boxes. After hovering at say 5th box, the ones on its left move -81px(to the left), and the ones on its right move 81px(to the right).

So the one that has not been transformed (the one which we are hovering onto) still has the same width as it had before even though its width is set to 100%. Can someone please explain to me why can't the space left from the transformed elements be used from the one in the middle ?

You can see it in action [here](https://jsbin.com/meretut/edit?css,output)

```
//css:
.boxwrapper{
  display:block;
  >div{
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    width:auto;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:white;
    &.before{
      transform:translateX(-20px);
    }&.after{
      transform:translateX(20px);
    }
  }
}

//html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="boxwrapper">
  <div data-number="1" id="box" onmouseover="mouseoverbox(event)" onmouseleave="removeAll()">BOX 1</div>
  <div data-number="2" id="box" onmouseover="mouseoverbox(event)" onmouseleave="removeAll()">BOX 2</div>
  <div data-number="3" id="box" onmouseover="mouseoverbox(event)" onmouseleave="removeAll()">BOX 3</div>
  <div data-number="4" id="box" onmouseover="mouseoverbox(event)" onmouseleave="removeAll()">BOX 4</div>
  <div data-number="5" id="box" onmouseover="mouseoverbox(event)" onmouseleave="removeAll()">BOX 5</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Transformations [don't affect the flow](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-rendering) of elements, only the visual rendering. I know it looks like the div should have more space and be able to expand but in reality it doesn't.

Comment: Okay that's what I suspected, but do you know any workaround to this, or is absolute positioning my only friend in this scenario ?

Comment: I would look into flexbox.